# Stying large data - flex or gird?

Tags: css, gridview, flexbox

I have a large amount of data to style.  It comes in for each file rather and each type and needs to be displayed in a grid/table way, however due to the html it is causing problems.  Some of the data rows are blank and others go over multiple lines.

I can't use a table as this would mean that the cells are going to go horizontal instead of vertical

See fiddle
https://jsfiddle.net/r5aj7kse/

```css
.data {
    display: flex
}

.dataColumn {
  flex-grow: 1;
  flex-basis: 0;
 }

.dataRow {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #000;
  padding: 4px;
}
```

```html
<div class="data">
 <div class="dataColumn">
    <div class="dataRow">A</div>
    <div class="dataRow">B</div>
    <div class="dataRow"></div>
    <div class="dataRow">D</div>
 </div>
 <div class="dataColumn">
    <div class="dataRow">A<br>A</div>
    <div class="dataRow">B</div>
    <div class="dataRow">C</div>
    <div class="dataRow">D</div>
 </div>
```

I need all of the cells to match up.  I have tried using flex and the only way I can get it to work is to add a fixed height to the cells but this is problematic as i lose alot of data this way

Comment: I should also point out that I do not know how many dataColumns or dataRows I will be receiving each call

Comment: This is tabular data so you should be using a `table`

Answer (score 0):

Use table instead of div.

```css
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
th,
td {
  border: 1px solid #c6c7cc;
  padding: 10px 15px;
}
th {
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th scope="col" colspan="1">Item</th>
      <th scope="col">Qty</th>
      <th scope="col">table</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>A</td>
     
      <td>1</td>
      <td>text</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>B</td>
     
      <td>1</td>
      <td>text</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>C</td>
      
      <td>1</td>
      <td>text</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>D</td>
      
      <td>1</td>
      <td>text</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
  
</table>
```

Comment: the data comes in top down so I get all the data for file 1 and then file 2 etc.  This would give me an inverse table

Answer (score -1):

If it possible, you can arrange data in rows, like this:

```
 <div class="data">
     <div class="dataRow">
        <div class="dataCol">A</div>
        <div class="dataCol">A</div>
        <div class="dataCol">A</div>
     </div>
     <div class="dataRow">
        <div class="dataRow">B</div>
        <div class="dataRow">B</div>
        <div class="dataRow">B</div>
     </div>
     <div class="dataRow">
        <div class="dataRow">C</div>
        <div class="dataRow">C</div>
        <div class="dataRow">C</div>
     </div>
     <div class="dataRow">
        <div class="dataRow">D</div>
        <div class="dataRow">D</div>
        <div class="dataRow">D</div>
     </div>
 </div>
```

but better choice use <table> for big data-table

Comment: unfortunately not.  The data comes in for each sheet which would be A, B, C etc